# Find next box class and close it

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

All,
I've got the following JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HHtBX/11/

I'm trying to basically close all the other boxes that are open. So after it does the onClick and Toggles that one open I try and close everything else.

The toggles part work fine but I can't close the open boxes. Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you give us some code to look at, your question is to vague.  Never mind... duh :-)

Comment: @NathanBunney I added a JS Fiddle which has all the code I'm trying to work with

Comment: Yup, that was the duh edit!  :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

like this: http://jsfiddle.net/49bWx/ by adding:

```
    $('.trigger.active').not(this).toggleClass("active").next().slideToggle('slow');
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this

```
  $(".trigger").click(function() { 
    $(this).toggleClass("active").next().slideToggle('slow', function(){
        $('.box').not(this).slideUp('slow');    
    });
    return false;
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Hide all expanded  items ( with class box) on the onclick event.

```
$(".trigger").click(function() { 
    $(".box").slideUp(); 
    $(this).toggleClass("active").next().slideToggle('slow');
    return false;
}).find(".box").next().slideToggle('slow');
```

Here is the working sample : http://jsfiddle.net/HHtBX/13/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".tb-toggle").each(function(){
    $(this).find(".box").hide();
});

$(".trigger").click(function() {
    $(".tb-toggle").each(function(){
        $(this).find(".box").hide();
    });

    $(this).toggleClass("active").next().slideToggle('slow');
    return false;
}).find(".box").next().slideToggle('slow');
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$(".trigger").click(function() { 
  $(".box").slideUp('slow');
  $(this).toggleClass("active").next().slideToggle('slow');    
  return false;    
});
```

​

Comment: @ArmritpalSingh Thanks, if I click on the one that is already open it closes it and then opens it again. How can I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/HHtBX/14/ try this ,

```
    var next=$(this).toggleClass("active").next();
    next.slideToggle('slow');
    $('.box:visible').not(next).slideToggle('slow');
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to hide all other boxes when this one is opened?

```
$(".tb-toggle").each(function(){
    $(this).find(".box").hide();
});

$(".trigger").click(function() { 
    $(this).toggleClass("active").next().slideToggle('slow');
    $(".trigger.active").not(this).removeClass("active").next().slideUp('slow');
    return false;
}).find(".box").next().slideToggle('slow');
```

​I put it on fiddle [http://jsfiddle.net/HHtBX/18/](http://jsfiddle.net/HHtBX/16/)

​